# Determining differences between curves with the K-S test

Tags: distributions, nonparametric, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I'm running an experiment where my treatments have a significant and highly sensitive effect of the distribution of a result.

For example, if i alter a certain nutrient in a vegetable, the proportion of big leaves to medium leaves to small leaves is altered and is not normally distributed. my wish is to select a treatment level that skews the distribution of leaf sizes to a hypothetical ideal distribution (also not a normal one). so as you can see, i have to compare my data's non-normal distribution to a hypothetical distribution which is also not normal. both distributions are discrete since the x variates are the leaf sizes and the y variates are the proportions.

Here's my current thought process which i want to validate (or not) with you guys:
I want to use the Kolmogorov-smirnov test to compare each treatment's resultant distribution of leaves to the hypothetical distribution. I read that the p-values K-S test are invalid for discrete data, but the D statistic is valid. so i want to calculate the D statistic for each of my treatments against the null distribution, then simply choose the treatment with the lowest D statistic.

Is this a valid option? if not, are there any better ways to do it?

i cant do a chi-square test because the curves are not normally distributed, and i don't want to transform the data because i feel like i'll be stretching it a little bit since my sample sizes per treatment are small.

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Your responses are counts? (number of small, medium and large leaves)... also, how is the theoretical distribution obtained?

Comment: @Glen_b yes my responses are counts as you suggested. obtained by simply counting the number of leaves in each category. the distributions become apparent when i plot histograms  of the frequencies of each category. in some cases it looks exponential (as in 70% small leaves, 20% medium, 10% small) in some cases it looks normally distributed, in some cases it looks polynomial. i'd like to have a measure that calculates how far each distribution is from a hypothetical distribution. with the idea of selecting the one with the least difference from the hypothetical distribution.